# How can I create SCALABLE HTML5-banner? Which would full 100% of the screen.

Tags: html

We need to create HTML5 banner, which would not have fix size but would be scalable and fit 100% of screen by width and by height. Banner is rather simple, but it should look good as on 320x480 as on 1024x768.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If using an SVG image is acceptable, I would create one that looks good at both extremes of the scale (make sure it remains readable in low resolution), then put it into a `<div class="span12">` element using a responsive layout with something like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). Your banner will scale nicely as the size of the screen is being changed by the user.

If you can't use SVG, then use JPEG or PNG, design the banner in the highest resolution, and make sure that it remains readable when using the lowest resolution you want to support.

If you want to be really fancy, you could skip the image altogether and design your banner as a bunch of HTML5 code, with CSS and possibly JavaScript code that would display different content depending on the size of the screen, but that could be quite a bit of work and it might not be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can make full screen banner section with 100% full screen with width 100%: and height:100%; , here have tips and live link

```
#bannersection {
position: relative;
display: table;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(99,214,250,1);
height: 100vh;
}
```

https://www.htmllion.com/fullscreen-header-banner-section.html